# Get user account group using windows principle

Tags: c#

I have a quick question.

Actually i am working in windows environment version 10.0.16299.0 and UWP. What i am trying to do is get information about user account info, its name and if its admin or user, shortly code looks like this:

```
public class Priciple
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string AccountDomainSid { get; set; }

    public List<string> Claims { get; set; }

    public string AdminRole { get; set; }

    public string UserRole { get; set; }

    public void GetUserInfo()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);

        UserName = identity.Name;
        AccountDomainSid = identity.User?.AccountDomainSid.Value ?? "Unknown";
        Claims = identity.Claims.Select(claim => claim.Value).ToList();

        AdminRole = $"Admin role {principal.IsInRole(@"BUILTIN\Administrators")}";
        UserRole = $"User role {principal.IsInRole(@"BUILTIN\Users")}";
    }
}
```

Now, I am getting list of SID and username and other stuff, so simple display of class looks like:

> User Name - DESKTOP-ISLHFK5\Administrator Domain Sid - S-1-5-21-134928182-1594639943-345264679 
>    Local Account an groups Sid: 
>    DESKTOP-ISLHFK5\Administrator
>   S-1-5-21-134928182-1594639943-345264679-500 - as far I understand this is administrator account
>   S-1-5-21-134928182-1594639943-345264679-513
>   S-1-5-21-134928182-1594639943-345264679-513
>   S-1-1-0
>   S-1-5-114
>   S-1-5-21-134928182-1594639943-345264679-1002
>   S-1-5-21-134928182-1594639943-345264679-1051
>   S-1-5-32-544
>   S-1-5-32-562
>   S-1-5-32-559
>   S-1-5-32-545
>   S-1-5-14
>   S-1-5-4
>   S-1-5-11
>   S-1-5-15
>   S-1-5-113
>   S-1-2-0
>   S-1-5-64-10

But as i check for admin i am getting:

> Priviliges info Admin role False

Now any idea why is that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's explained in the documentation of [WindowsBuiltInRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsbuiltinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> In Windows Vista, User Account Control (UAC) determines the privileges of a user. If you are a member of the Built-in Administrators group, you are assigned two run-time access tokens: a standard user access token and an administrator access token.
>
> By default, you are in the standard user role. When you attempt to
> perform a task that requires administrative privileges, you can
> dynamically elevate your role by using the Consent dialog box. The
> code that executes the IsInRole method does not display the Consent
> dialog box. The code returns false if you are in the standard user
> role, even if you are in the Built-in Administrators group.
>
> You can elevate your privileges before you execute the code by right-clicking
> the application icon and indicating that you want to run as an
> administrator.

Try again with `myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)` to check if the account is an administrator

Answer (score 1):

Would you try to use `WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator`;

```
var AdminRole = $"Admin role {principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)}";
```